# How to link items from a tabbar item to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `UITabbar` and added additional `UITab Bar Items`. I then want to link (create a segue) to another view controller, but when I drag to create a segue, I do not get the popup menu letting me choose between 'push' and 'modal'.

How can I create a segue to another view controller?

Comment: You cannot trigger a segue using a tab bar item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create a segue inside the Interface Builder using a `UITab Bar Items`, it has to be done using a `UITabViewController` (dragging directly from it).

A workaround could be to do it programmatically, listening when a item is selected inside the UITabbar and use the `pushViewController:animated:` method from the navigation controller to make the push, but not sure if this will work.